# Ways to perform a sort for multiple data

Tags: c#, vb.net

I was using a ListView to display Items but I removed it and I am trying to sort data without having a visual component. what do you guys recommend for this type of data.

```
    Dim eProducts As New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, String())
    eProducts("759504") = {"Nike Shoes", "75.50", "9/29/2014", "Description"}
```

I need a way to sort products by (ID, Name, Price, Date, and Description). whats the best for this Array, List, Dictionary?

Comment: I am not sure if dictoanaries support LINQ but arrays and list does, the way to make it easy is LINQ

Comment: This doesn't seem like a particularly elegant approach to whatever you're trying to do. Could we see some more examples, and how you'd like them sorted?

Comment: I can do this really easy with tables in MySQL and sort by DESC and ASC but now I cant seem to find the right control on .Net that would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a class or struct to define a product type for your products.

Then LINQ's [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method makes it easy to sort in memory arrays, i.e.

```
' Example products defined as anonymous types
Dim products() = { _
    New With { Key .Id=759504, .Name="Nike Shoes", .Price=75.5, .Date=#9/29/2014# }, _
    New With { Key .Id=759505, .Name="Puma Shoes", .Price=69.9, .Date=#9/30/2014# } _
}

' Sort by id ascending
Dim byId = products.OrderBy(Function(product) product.Id)                 
' Sort by price descending
Dim byPrice = products.OrderByDescending(Function(product) product.Price)
```